# MSAL Token to open office pages

Tags: xamarin.forms, access-token, azure-ad-msal

Is it possible to use the AUTH access token we got back from MSAL on a mobile app to open an office365 page in the browser, like mail or calendar, etc. without having to re-auth the user?
I can send the token in the header, but can't find any requirements specs out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible today: the token you get from AAD is for your app - not for Office. In addition, users may be logged on the browser for example with a user that is different than the user signed-in to your application.